# Scoping issue react parent-child method ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im currently a little stuck with the following.

```
function Tag(props){
    let {text, onRemove, key} = props;
    return (
        <span onClick={onRemove(key)} key={key}>{text}</span>
    )
}

function TagInput (props) {
    let {onChange, value, onKeyDown} = props;
    return (
        <input type="text" onChange={onChange} value={value} onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
    )
}

class TagsInput extends Component {
    render() {
        let { Tag, TagInput, state } = this.props;
        console.log(state.tags);
        return (
            <div ref="div" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
                {state.tags.map((tag) =>
                    <Tag
                        text={tag.text}
                        key={tag.id}
                        onRemove={this.handleRemove}
                    />
                )}
                <TagInput
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                    onKeyDown={(e) => this.handleKeyDown(e)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    }

    handleChange(e){
        //console.log(e.target.value);
    }

    handleKeyDown(e){
        //console.log('keycode', e.keyCode);
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
            dispatch(addTag(e.target.value));
        }
        if (e.keyCode === 8 && e.target.value.length === 0) {
            dispatch(removeTag());
        }
    }

    handleRemove(id){
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(removeTag(id));
    }
}

TagsInput.propTypes = {
    TagInput: React.PropTypes.func,
    Tag: React.PropTypes.func,
    removeKeyCodes: React.PropTypes.array,
    addKeyCodes: React.PropTypes.array
};

TagsInput.defaultProps = {
    TagInput: TagInput,
    Tag: Tag,
    removeKeyCodes: [8],
    addKeyCodes: [9, 13]
};
```

I get the following error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` from method `handleRemove` line `const { dispatch } = this.props`. It seems like a scoping issue but I cannot seem to understand why this (no pun intended lol) is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 classes do not automatically bind `this` to functions with the exception of the ones provided by extending `Component` such as `componentDidMount` etc..

[from the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html)

The ES6 way - bind `this` to your methods in your constructor, OR where you call them:

```
class TagsInput extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleRremove = this.handleRemove.bind(this)
  }

  OR

  render() {
    return (
     <Tag   
       onRemove={this.handleRemove.bind(this)}
     />
  }
```

The ES7 way #1: bind syntax

```
this.handleRemove = ::this.handleRemove
```

The ES7 way #2: class arrow functions (I think this is the best way):

```
handleRemove = (id) => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    dispatch(removeTag(id));
}
```

Then call it like:

```
onRemove={ () => this.handleRemove(tag.id) }
```

UPDATE: Read @Road's answer as well. When binding the method *at point of use* you need to pass the argument along.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding `this`? Try `this.handleRemove.bind(this, tag.id)`. The `tag.id` there is the argument you're passing since `handleRemove(id)` needs an `id` as an arg.